# django-ldap auth and django 1.6 deprecated warning on user_profile

Tags: python, django, openldap, django-auth-ldap

On using django-auth-ldap (1.2.0) with django 1.6 on my linux running python 2.7 I get the warning:

> ```
> The use of AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to define user profiles has been deprecated.
>   profile = self._user.get_profile()
> ```

My settings.py contain LDAP settings:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType

# Keep ModelBackend around for per-user permissions and maybe a local
# superuser.
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://127.0.0.1"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=ram Krishna,ou=users,dc=test,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "ram"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=test,dc=com",
                                   ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
```

No other settings for LDAP in this py file

My slapd entry with ldapsearch -x shows:

```
# ram Krishna, users, test.com
dn: cn=ram Krishna,ou=users,dc=test,dc=com
cn: ram Krishna
mail: ram@y.com
givenName: ram
sn: Krishna
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
uid: ram
```

Why am I not able to authenticate?

Comment: I have checked the sample code on https://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap/example.html and see no mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same warning but my ldap works fine.

I only see 2 difference between your LDAP settings and mine

```
1. AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "???@test.com"
2. AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=test,dc=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, u"(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)")
```